# MySQL Query with JOIN Not executing correctly

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm not getting any data, and I've checked my dad which should match up

I have two tables, `likes` and `user_follow`
I'm trying to tie the two tables by an id.

**Table - Column**

`likes` - idlikes, iduser, information
`user_follow` - iduser_follow, iduser_follower, iduser_following

```
$following = $dbh -> prepare("SELECT L.* FROM likes L JOIN user_follow F ON F.iduser_following = L.iduser WHERE F.iduser_follower = ?");
$following->execute(array($_SESSION['user_auth']));
while($row_following = $following->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
     $id_1 = $row_following['L.information']; // get id of user that i'm following
     echo $id_1;
}
```

So if i'm following someone, i should be able to display information associated with whomever I'm following.

I don't get any errors, it just doesn't echo out anything?

---

Sample Data

`user_follow`

```
iduser_follow           iduser_follower            iduser_following
     1                         2                        3
     2                         2                        4
```

`likles`

```
  idlikes                   iduser                  information
     1                         3                        info1
     2                         3                        info2
```

So, I should output info1 and info2, assuming that $_SESSION['user_auth'] = 2, correct?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski sorry, that was a typo. Do you see anything else wrong with this? Or is it my database that I should recheck?

Comment: You fixed it in the fetch, but the query still has `R.iduser`.

Comment: If you execute the query in a MySQL client, do you get the result you expect? Post sample data from the tables.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski I added a table example. Hmm. I just tested on MySQL client, and it did pop out something, but I tested out without the PDO and fetch syntax

Comment: Do you have PDO throwing exceptions? Default is silent errors.  `$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);`

Comment: remove the `alias` on fetching data `$id_1 = $row_following['information'];`

Comment: @JW. Good grief how could I miss that.

Comment: You ought to turn on error reporting. You would have seen `Notice undefined index L.information`.  `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Thanks for the help. How do i write the error reporting syntax? I'm still learning PDO.

Comment: @andrewliu The two statements I put in the previous comment are not related to PDO, but general PHP error reporting. Just put them at the top of your script during development.  Check the [PDO docs on error handling](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php) for examples of different ways to set it up, as appropriate for the rest of your application. For example, if you don't typically use exceptions, use ERRMODE_WARNING.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  b.*
FROM    user_follow a
        INNER JOIN likes b
            ON a.iduser_following = b.iduser
WHERE   a.iduser_follow = 'myuserID' AND
        iduser_following = 'followingID'
```

and fetch value

```
$id_1 = $row_following['information'];
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Goodness! I've been trying to figure this out for an hour now :(